# The covariance of the inversion number and the Major Index

Tags: probability-theory, permutations

In [*The Joy of Brute Force*](http://sites.math.rutgers.edu/~zeilberg/mamarim/mamarimPDF/brute.pdf), Doron Zeilberger wrote:
$
\def\inv{\mathop{\rm inv} \nolimits}
\def\maj{\mathop{\rm maj} \nolimits}
\def\des{\mathop{\rm des} \nolimits}
$

> As usual, for a permutation $\pi$ of length $n$, let $\inv \pi$ be the
>   number of $(i,j)$, such that $1 \leq i <j \leq n$ and $\pi[i]>\pi[j]$,
>   and $\maj \pi$ be the sum of $i$, such that $1 \leq i <n$ and
>   $\pi[i]>\pi[i+1]$. Svante Janson asked Don Knuth, who asked me, about
>   the covariance of $\inv$ and $\maj$. The answer is ${{n} \choose
> > {2}}/4$. To prove it, I asked Shalosh to compute the average of the
>   quantity  $(\inv \pi - E(\inv))(\maj \pi - E(\maj)) $ over all
>   permutations of a given length $n$, and it gave me, for $n=1,2,3,4,5$,
>   the values $0,1/4,3/4,3/2,5/2$, respectively. Since we know a
>   priori that this is a polynomial of degree $\leq 4$, this must be it!

Why the covariance must be a polynomial of $n$ of degree $\leq 4$? It does not seem so obvious. The clue given by Zeilberger is:

> This is the old trick to compute moments of combinatorial
>   statistics, described nicely in Graham, Knuth, and Patashnik's
>   Concrete Math, section 8.2, by changing the order of summation. It
>   applies equally well to covariance.  Rather than actually carrying out
>   the gory details, we observe that this is always a polynomial whose
>   degree is trivial to bound.

I checked that section of Concrete Math, but I am not sure which part is related.